# How do I remove adhesive from outdoor concrete deck that is textured?

Tags: concrete

I have an outdoor deck that had the old green carpet truf glued down. I removed it some time ago and want to remove the adhesive from the concrete, it has the brushed finish so the adhesive is in the texture how would I remove the old adhesive with out using chemicals and scrapping?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet in this case is a pressure washer.  If that doesn't work by itself you can put some solvent on it to soften it up, let it sit a few minutes then pressure wash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a heat gun and a putty knife. Heat a section until the adhesive softens, and then scrape it off. That should get most of it off.

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be an angle grinder with a wire wheel cup.

[image]